# Group latest values in pandas columns for a given id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing some metrics for a given date and user.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({"user": ['juan','juan','juan','gonzalo'], "date": [1, 2, 3, 1], "var1": [1, 2, None, 1], "var2": [None, 4, 5, 6]})
      user  date  var1  var2
0     juan     1   1.0   NaN
1     juan     2   2.0   4.0
2     juan     3   NaN   5.0
3  gonzalo     1   1.0   6.0
```

Now, for each user, I want to extract the 2 more recent values for each variable (var1, var2) ignoring `NaN` unless there aren't enough values to fill the data.

For reference, this should be the resulting dataframe for the data depicted above

```
user     var1_0  var1_1  var2_0  var2_1
juan       2.0     1.0     5.0    4.0
gonzalo    1.0      NaN    6.0    NaN
```

each "historical" value is added as a new column with a `_0` or `_1` suffix.

Comment: is `date` the column to sort by to get recent or the row order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sorting if necessary by both columns in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and remove missing values, filter top2 rrows per groups by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html), then create counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with pivoting in [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['user','date'])
         .melt(id_vars='user', value_vars=['var1','var2'])
         .dropna(subset=['value'])
        )


df1 = df1.groupby(['user','variable']).head(2)
df1['g'] = df1.groupby(['user','variable']).cumcount(ascending=False)

df1 = df1.pivot(index='user', columns=['variable', 'g'], values='value')
#oldier pandas versions
#df1 = df1.set_index(['user','variable', 'g'])['value'].unstack([1,2])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
      user  var1_0  var1_1  var2_0  var2_1
0  gonzalo     1.0     NaN     6.0     NaN
1     juan     2.0     1.0     5.0     4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, works as expected. Even better as I also have my dataframe without pivoting, so I don't even need the `.melt()`

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `user` and aggregate to get the 2 most recent values. That get's almost all the way there - but instead of columns you have a list of elements. If you want to have the actual 2 columns you have to split the newly created list into columns. Full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user": ["juan", "juan", "juan", "gonzalo"],
        "date": [1, 2, 3, 1],
        "var1": [1, 2, None, 1],
        "var2": [None, 4, 5, 6],
    }
)

# This almost gets you there
df = (
    df.sort_values(by="date")
    .groupby("user")
    .agg({"var1": lambda x: x.dropna().head(2), "var2": lambda x: x.dropna().head(2)})
)

# Split the columns and get the correct column names
df[["var1_0", "var2_0"]] = df[["var1", "var2"]].apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series(el[0] if isinstance(el, np.ndarray) else el for el in row),
    axis=1,
)
df[["var1_1", "var2_1"]] = df[["var1", "var2"]].apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series(el[-1] if isinstance(el, np.ndarray) else None for el in row),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)

>>
               var1        var2  var1_0  var2_0  var1_1  var2_1
user                                                           
gonzalo         1.0         6.0     1.0     6.0     NaN     NaN
juan     [1.0, 2.0]  [4.0, 5.0]     1.0     4.0     2.0     5.0
```